# error while filling dataframe on condition basis

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function that compares if the specific time is in between two values

```
def is_time_between(begin_time, end_time, check_time=None):
# If check time is not given, default to current UTC time
check_time = check_time or datetime.utcnow().time()
if begin_time < end_time:
    return check_time >= begin_time and check_time <= end_time
else: # crosses midnight
    return check_time >= begin_time or check_time <= end_time
```

The function works fine. I want to use the following function in order to compare the time values if the data frame and fille other column based on this condition as the following

```
if is_time_between(time(5,0), time(12,59),df.time):
    df['day_interval'] = 1
elif is_time_between(time(13,0), time(17,59),df['time']):
    df['day_interval'] = 2
elif is_time_between(time(18,0), time(23,59),df['time']):
    df['day_interval'] = 3
else:
    df['day_interval']= 4
```

running the following code raises the folloiwng error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for return mask by column values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-10-1 01:00:10',
                           '2019-10-2 14:00:10',
                           '2019-10-31 19:00:10',
                           '2019-10-31 06:00:10']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.time
print(df)
                  date      time
0   2019-10-1 01:00:10  01:00:10
1   2019-10-2 14:00:10  14:00:10
2  2019-10-31 19:00:10  19:00:10
3  2019-10-31 06:00:10  06:00:10
```

---

```
m1 = df['time'].apply(lambda x: is_time_between(time(5,0), time(12,59), x))
m2 = df['time'].apply(lambda x: is_time_between(time(13,0), time(17,59), x))
m3 = df['time'].apply(lambda x: is_time_between(time(18,0), time(23,59), x))

df['day_interval'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [1,2,3], default=4)
```

Another solution with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and converting times to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
bins = pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:00','05:00:00','13:00:00','18:00:00','23:59:59'])
df['day_interval1'] = pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)), bins, labels=[4,1,2,3])

print (df)
                  date      time  day_interval day_interval1
0   2019-10-1 01:00:10  01:00:10             4             4
1   2019-10-2 14:00:10  14:00:10             2             2
2  2019-10-31 19:00:10  19:00:10             3             3
3  2019-10-31 06:00:10  06:00:10             1             1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your answer @jezrael